# Interfacing with Xilinx virtex-5 FPGA board

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx-ise, virtex

i have been working with spartan 3e starter kit board for long time. But now i am trying to work with virtex-5 ml505 xc5vlx110t board(ff1136). And the very first problem that I am facing is that xilinx ise 14.7 does not have package of this board(it has packages till vlx50t only). I updated my license file but it didn't help. I thought that it might be an installation problem so i installed xilinx ise 14.2. Apparently this version has the package of virtex-5 ml505 xc5vlx110t board(ff1136) but it is giving an error while synthesizing that: the license is not found for this architecture. While it is synthesizing the same code without any error for virtex-5 ml505 xc5vlx50 board(ff1136). i have updated my license file from Xilinx's website but it is not helping. Do i need to buy some license for this architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your *WebPack license* with all FPGAs. It's just for entry-level customer boards with popular chips.

You'll need to buy a full license or have a look into your FPGA board's package. Some resellers sell the boards with a  *node locked license*. This license enables all features off a full license, but restricted to the FPGA type sold by you reseller.